# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in handler.php on line 62

Tags: php

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cmp255/Final/Change
>   Maker/handler.php on line 62

I keep seeing this error when I run my code.
**This is line 62**

```
$fiveC = 0.05 * $_POST['fiveCent'];
```

**This is what its getting data from**

```
<p>$0.05<input type="number" name="fiveCent" ></p>
```

Could I get any help?

Comment: New people don't get certain stuff if its not related to their code

Answer (score 0):

I'd call `floatval` on your incoming POST parameter to cast that to a float value, whether its a string or float-like.

So try

```
       $fiveC = 0.05 * floatval($_POST['fiveCent']);
```

Comment: Cody Thank you very much for answering the question it really helped.